# Invalidate session on changing Auth0 SSO password in Outsystems

Tags: auth0, change-password, outsystems

We are using Auth0 to authenticate users in Outsystems traditional web.
On changing the password the sessions should be invalidated for that specific user.
I went through the documentation in Auth0 and not finding any info to  to invalidate sessions in OUtsystems.

If anyone have luck with the implementation can kindly let me know how this can be achieved?

Comment: That depends on your session implementation, doesn't it?